# Modifying parameter passed by value has no effect on caller's variable

Tags: c++, winapi, assembly

I'm trying to make a function that scales the controls of a window with its parent window when I resize that window, in order to accomplish this I embedded `CreateWindowEx()` into my own function `createscalingwindow`

```
int createscalingwindow (HWND cswpara0,DWORD cswpara1,const CHAR* cswpara2,
const CHAR* cswpara3,DWORD cswpara4,int cswpara5,int cswpara6,int cswpara7,
int cswpara8,HWND cswpara9,HMENU cswpara10,HINSTANCE cswpara11,LPVOID cswpara12)
              {
               cswpara0 = CreateWindowEx (cswpara1, cswpara2, cswpara3, cswpara4,
                                          cswpara5,cswpara6,cswpara7,cswpara8,
                                         cswpara9,cswpara10,cswpara11,cswpara12);
               return 0;
              }
```

After changing this code in winmain

```
    mainwin = CreateWindowEx(
       0,                   
       mainclassname,         
       "Mafia Online",       
       WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_CAPTION|WS_THICKFRAME|WS_MINIMIZEBOX|WS_MAXIMIZEBOX
      |WS_SYSMENU, 
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       
       CW_USEDEFAULT,       
       544,                 
       375,                 
       NULL,        
       playmenu,                
       hThisInstance,       
       NULL                 
       );
```

To the following code

```
createscalingwindow (mainwin, 0, mainclassname, "Mafia Online",
WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_CAPTION|WS_THICKFRAME|WS_MINIMIZEBOX|WS_MAXIMIZEBOX|WS_SYSMENU, 
CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 544, 375, NULL, playmenu, hThisInstance, NULL);
ShowWindow (mainwin, nCmdShow);
```

The main window no longer shows up at all. Calling `GetLastError()` after the embedded `CreateWindowEx()` returns error_success.

After examining both variants of the program in ollydbg, I noticed something strange, the execution of the program using the prototype doesn't work the way I'd expect. The program calls to `CreateWindowEx` and then returns from the call to an entirely different destination.

Here's how I would expect the program to execute (this is the program that doesn't use `createscalingwindow`):
(I am not allowed to post images as a new user, so if a mod or someone could fix these for me that would be nice.)
http://s8.postimage.org/qo8tqt5h1/mainnormal.png

Here's how it executes:
http://s8.postimage.org/fa8ytr7qt/mainweird.png

Any effort you put forth into helping me is appreciated, so thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to pass `cswpara0` by reference.

Comment: @aleguna HWND is a pointer to begin with.

Comment: @johnathon, it doesn't matter in `createscalingwindow` he is modifying a local copy of the HWND which is why it has no effect on callers copy.

Comment: Raymond Chen's edit gives away the answer in the question title. Very nice. @johnathon: that doesn't matter, the caller is calling `ShowWindow` on a garbage handle.

Comment: @aleguna I'm actually a super noob at c++, how do I do that if I may ask?

Comment: @user1934608 HWND &cswpara0 as the paramater

Comment: @aleguna and DCoder yea, I need more coffee.

Comment: [When I change a parameter inside a function, does it change for the caller, too?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698660/when-i-change-a-parameter-inside-a-function-does-it-change-for-the-caller-too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, function arguments are passed by value, meaning that the function gets its own copy of the variable, and not a reference to the caller's variable. Any modifications made to the local copy will not affect whatever was passed to the function.

If you want a reference, then pass by reference:

```
int createscalingwindow (HWND & cswpara0 /* etc. */)
                              ^
```

Now any modifications you make to the function argument will also modify the caller's variable.