# How to modify a string in a function?

Tags: c++, string, function, pointers

Say I have

```
string stringInput = "hello";

alter(stringInput);

cout << stringInput;
```

and a function:

```
void alter(string stringIn){
     stringIn[0] = stringIn[3];
}
```

Ideally I would want cout to produce "lello". But right now it simply returns "hello" as originally. I know this has something to do with addresses and pointers... how would I achieve this?

Comment: Pass the string by reference instead of by value.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698660/when-i-change-a-parameter-inside-a-function-does-it-change-for-the-caller-too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stringIn is a local variable. So when you pass it on the function as a value it just makes a new stringIn with  different address. So the changes you are making in alter is only affecting the new stringIn. You need to recieve the reference of the stringIn in `alter` to make it work.

```
void alter(string& stringIn){

 stringIn[0] = stringIn[3];
}
```

Comment: That's not a pointer, nor is it the only way to solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry wanted to make string& bold. Thats why those extra * was there. Edited.

Comment: It's still not a pointer.

Comment: @Aesthete He could have meant that references are mostly implemented with pointers. :-)

Comment: @kalkin Your function argument is a reference, not a pointer. But your text says something about passing a pointer. Will you correct this?

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do is to pass the string by reference:

```
void alter(string& stringIn){
     //          ^
     stringIn[0] = stringIn[3];
}
```

You should also modify accordingly any function declarations you have for `alter()`.

Comment: do I need to do the same in my prototype/declaration above main()?

Comment: @Gnuey Sure. It must match with the function definition.

Comment: I'm a bit confused why we would pass the address of stringIn, since & refers to "address of" right? I thought a string is already a reference  to addresses. By putting & in front of the parameter, will the parameter name called inside the definition be a "reference to a reference"? Or is that not true and the brackets simply dereference a reference?

Comment: @Gnuey See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29

Comment: @Gnuey I think what you are saying is true for arrays. but strings are objects that represent sequences of characters.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually just because a new copy of the string is created for use in the function. To modify the string directly in the function add an & before the string name in the function header like this:

```
 void alter(string &stringIn){
```

That passes the string by reference. Otherwise you could just return a string from the function.