# Is separate memory location created for n or both m or n point to the same location?

Tags: c++

Can anyone make me clear what these lines of code are doing? Is the value of m being copied to the memory location of `n`? Or `n` is also pointing to the same address as `m`?  And how?

```
int m=5;
int &n=m;
```

Comment: It says "'m' and 'n' are different names for the same thing".

Comment: While you ask what both lines are doing, I'm reading into your question that it's mostly about the meaning of the specific line `int &n = m;`.   Does this answer your question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46969031/when-is-a-reference-variable-appropriate-and-why-can-you-explain-the-actual-syn  Or this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c

Comment: @molbdnilo can you explain how?

Comment: @DrewDormann that post is quite complex I guess ..can you explain that in your own words?

Comment: You know how "My name is William, but you can call me Bill" works? Same thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765999/what-is-a-reference-variable-in-c)

Comment: The `&` here makes `n` a reference to an `int` and `int &n = m` makes it so that `n` is essentially just an alias for `m`. What this actually compiles to will depend on what happens in the rest of the code. If it can be statically determined that `n` always points to this `m` then essentially `n` doesn't exist after compilation (no memory used for it etc.). In other scenarios, if what `n` points to is determined in run-time, then it will be something similar to a pointer (so some form of storage will most likely be required).

Comment: @odyss-jii thanks sir I thought this  had something to do with the memory locations as pointers do hehe

Comment: `m` is a [C++ Object](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object), it has size, storage, lifetime etc.  `n` is __not__ a C++ Object; the declaration `int &n=m;` is just an instruction the to the compiler to treat any use of `n` as __an alias__ for `m`.  There is no requirement for the compiler to use any memory to store `n` (although it can if needs to).

Answer (score 1):

```
int m = 5;
```

The above line makes a new variable of type `int` and assigns it the value `5`.

```
int &n = m;
```

This makes a reference variable of type `int` and assigns `m` to it. This means that `n` is basically another name for `m`, and if `n`'s value is changed, `m`'s value will change as well. It's kinda like `pointers`, but way more high level than `pointers`.

Comment: so is that what we call reference variable in c++?i.e. is n a reference variable of m?

Comment: You can say that. But more formally we say it as `n is an alias for m`.

Comment: I'd wouldn't say references are less complex. They are more abstract/high level concept than pointers. Sometimes they behave like const pointers, sometimes they're really just aliases.

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
int m = 5;
```

This line creates a variable of type `int` which contains the value `5`.

```cpp
int& n = m;
```

This line creates a **reference** to `m`. You can think of it as an alias to `m`. So this instruction :

```cpp
n = 6;
```

**Actually changes the value of `m`.**

References are typically (not always though, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954764/how-are-references-implemented-internally)) implemented as pointers internally. The compiler will typically reserve a location in memory where it will store the **memory adress** of `m`. This means that the following pieces of code are equivalent:

```cpp
int main() {
    int m = 5;
    int& n = m; // Reference
    n = 6;
}
```

```cpp
int main() {
    int m = 5;
    int* const n = &m; // Pointer const (meaning the held memory address 
                       // can't be changed, only the value at that address can be)
    *n = 6;
}
```

I personally only use `const` references, meaning **I can't modify the value of the values that is being referenced**. When I actually want to modify the referenced value, I use pointers because I think they provide more clarity (they basically say "I'm not owning this value, which means that when I modify it, expect a value somewhere else in the program to have changed.").

So when to use `const` references? Arguably their most frequent use case is **passing a function argument by reference**. For example, passing a `std::string` object to the following function actually **copies it**, which can be very expensive for large objects.

```cpp
#include <string>

void doStuffWithString(std::string str /* potentially expensive */) {
    // ...
}
```

Instead, you can pass it **by `const` reference**, meaning you don't pass the actual object to the function, but a `const` reference to it to prevent the unnecessary copy.

```cpp
#include <string>

void doStuffWithString(const std::string& str /* not expensive */) {
    // ...
}
```

If I ever want to modify the value of the object being passed, I pass it **by address** (with a pointer).

```cpp
#include <string>

void modifyString(std::string* str /* pointer */) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    std::string hiMom("Hi mom!");
    modifyString(&hiMom); // Explicitly shows the caller that we're passing
                          // a pointer, meaning the value of hiMom might change
    return 0;
}
```